# Inequality holds for all the domain

Tags: calculus, inequality

How can I show that the following inequality holds for any $0\leq y<x \leq 1$:
$$3xy^2 - y^3 - 3y + 2-x >0.$$

It seems to hold for the defined domain, but could not manipulate it accordingly. Any ideas?

Comment: seems false. Check what you typed in your question.

Comment: False. $x=0.8, y=0.75$, LHS=$-0.12188$.

Comment: I first thought that it holds and tried to prove it before I do some numerical analysis, anyway thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is does not true, but I found
$$3xy^2 - y^3 - 3y + 2-x \geqslant \boxed{2 - \frac{8\sqrt{6}}{9}} = -0.1773$$
Indeed, we write the inequality as
$$f(x) = (3y^2-1)x-y^3-3y+\frac{8\sqrt{6}}{9} \geqslant 0.$$
If $3y^2 \geqslant 1,$ then
$$f(x) > f(y) = 2y^3-4y+\frac{8\sqrt{6}}{9} = \frac{2(3y+2\sqrt{6})(3y-\sqrt{6})^2}{27} \geqslant 0.$$
If $3y^2 < 1,$ then
$$f(x) \geqslant f(1) = 3y^2-1-y^3-3y+\frac{8\sqrt{6}}{9} = (1-y)^3+\frac{8\sqrt{6}}{9}-2>0.$$

Comment: thanks very much, this is very helpful.